# GravCMS Docker Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grav

I have this docker-compose file:

```
---
services:
  grav:
    image: linuxserver/grav:latest
    container_name: test1
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
    volumes:
      - ..\grav\user\accounts:/var/www/grav/user/accounts
      - ..\grav\user\blueprints:/var/www/grav/user/blueprints
      - ..\config:/var/www/grav/user/config
      - ..\contents\data:/var/www/grav/user/data
      - ..\grav\user\images:/var/www/grav/user/images
      - ..\grav\user\languages:/var/www/grav/user/languages
      - ..\contents\posts:/var/www/grav/user/pages
      - ..\grav\user\plugins:/var/www/grav/user/plugins
      - ..\vendors\themes:/var/www/grav/user/themes
    ports:
      - 666:80
    restart: unless-stopped
```

the container starts well, but I do not see any content on my host folders. Where is the problem?

(ps: I am on windows, so the backslash is reversed on the config)

Comment: What code would copy content into these host directories?  A Docker volume mount always replaces the image content with the mounted directory (with a couple of corner cases) so unless you're copying content into the host directories somewhere the host directories will in fact be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The paths in the container are not correct, Grav is stored in `/app/www/public/` as shown in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-grav/blob/main/Dockerfile).